# Replacing OK Google

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am trying to build an app which has the same functionality as OK Google, except for a few additional commands specific to my app as well as replacing the "OK Google" key phrase with one specific to my app. My issue is that I don't want to implement all the code for every possible command that OK Google does, and was wondering if there was some way to pass on text to OK Google and have it do the same thing as if that text had been said following an "OK Google" keyword.

On the other hand, it would also be great to somehow replace the "OK Google" keyword on Google now with that of my apps if possible. Then I could just listen for a few keywords on my own apps speech recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **not** possible with Android Speech API. However you can use *pocketsphinx-android* to recognize whatever keyword you need. See this very [basic demo](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo) to learn how to setup recognizers and switch the searches. Note that your keyword must be present in the dictionary, so if it's absent in the default dictionary you will have to add it along with its transcription.